# How to specify alternating parameters in swagger?

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

Is it possible (and how) to specify additional parameters that depend on the value of another given parameter?

#### Example

I have a call `PUT /accounts/<account_id>/payment_method` which takes some parameters besides the path parameter.

One is `payment_method_type` which defines the payment method to be set.

Now: if `payment_method_type` is `DD` for direct debit, there are some more parameters allowed (and needed) like `account_holder` and `iban`.
If it is something else, e. g. `PP`, other parameters are needed.

#### Excerpt from the json

```
"parameters": {
  "payment_method_type": {
    "name": "type",
    "description": "Payment method type.",
    "in": "query",
    "required": true,
    "type": "string",
    "enum": [
      "DD", "IV", "PP"
    ]
  },
  "payment_method_data_dd_account_holder": {
    "name": "account_holder",
    "description": "Name of account holder",
    "in": "query",
    "required": false, # but true if payment_method_type == DD
    "type": "string"
  },
  "payment_method_data_dd_iban": {
    "name": "iban",
    "description": "IBAN",
    "in": "query",
    "required": false, # but true if payment_method_type == DD
    "type": "string"
  },
  "payment_method_data_pp_some_info": {
    "name": "some_info",
    "description": "Some info needed for PP",
    "in": "query",
    "required": false, # but true if payment_method_type == PP
    "type": "string"
  },
}
"paths": {
  "/accounts/{account_id}/payment_method": {
    "put": {
      "summary": "Update Payment Method",
      "description": "...",
      "parameters": {
        {
          "$ref": "#/parameters/path_psp_account_id"
        },
        {
          "$ref": "#/parameters/payment_method_type"
        },
        {
          "$ref": "#/parameters/payment_method_data_dd_account_holder"
        },
        {
          "$ref": "#/parameters/payment_method_data_dd_iban"
        },
        {
          "$ref": "#/parameters/payment_method_data_pp_some_info"
        },
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to get rid of the long parameter list (since there are more parameters left out here) but group them as described above and document that some parameters are required (and allowed) only for special types.

**Is there a way to describe this?**

**Is there a way to define sets of parameters like all the direct debit parameters in one definition and reference it?** *Remark*: those parameters are given next to the `payment_method_type` parameter and not inside a sub-object.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to have conditional parameters in the current swagger specification.

Yes, the parameters array allows a `$ref` pointer.